# Should a blog post based on a scientific paper have the same co-authors?

Tags: authorship, collaboration, blog, science-communication

I recently published a paper in a scholarly journal together with two co-authors. (I was the first author and the leader of that project.)

Having found a blog on this topic, I quickly penned down a summary of our findings in a more journalistic style.

Is there anything to consider regarding that blog post and the co-authors? Should I inform them before I submit the article to that blog? Should I even invite my paper-co-authors to edit the article so that they become co-authors of that blog post as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, I assume, you are writing *about* the paper you can submit it on your own. However it would be both polite and wise to get your co-authors involved. It might improve the result.

But authorship of a blog post isn't an especially valuable academic item even though it can be copyrighted. So, co-authorship shouldn't be an issue. Few would care.

Further discussions with your co authors might even lead to something new, generally a good thing.